# Postgresql - Interpreted type for NULL is wrong

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have the problem with the following CTE expression because `prev_count` in `new_values` is being interpreted as `text`, but the column I'm updating in `counts` is type `integer`. I'm getting this error on the marked line:

```
ERROR:  column "prev_count" is of type integer but expression is of type text
LINE 12:     prev_count = new_values.prev_count
```

Here's the query:

```
WITH  
    new_values (word,count,txid,prev_count) AS (
        VALUES ('cat',1,5,NULL)),
    updated AS (
        UPDATE 
            counts t 
        SET 
            count = new_values.count, 
            txid = new_values.txid, 
            prev_count = new_values.prev_count -- ERROR HERE
        FROM 
            new_values 
        WHERE (
            t.word = new_values.word
        ) 
    RETURNING t.*) 
INSERT INTO counts(
    word,count,txid,prev_count
) SELECT 
    word,count,txid,prev_count FROM new_values 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM updated WHERE (updated.word = new_values.word))
```

My question is, what's an elegant way to fix the error? I would rather specify the type of `prev_count` in `new_values` instead of adding an explicit cast, but I don't see anything like that in the docs.

Comment: Try using `null::integer` in your `values` clause

Comment: Maybe this question would be better suited to dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name would you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding this here as an explicit answer along with a detailed explanation.

The fix is:

```
WITH  
    new_values (word,count,txid,prev_count) AS (
        VALUES ('cat',1,5,NULL::text)),
```

As a_horse_with_no_name suggested in the comments.

Why is this necessary?  Because the row specification comes from the VALUES section and NULL is unknown.  In this case PostgreSQL helpfully casts to text.  But that is not what you want so you have to give a type to the NULL.

This often comes up in other cases too, such as `UNION` statements where a NULL in the first segment in the column list can be given an implicit type which clashes with the type of the column in another segment.  So this is a tricky corner worth knowing about.

Comment: It had never occurred to me that `NULL` values still have the column's type, but I guess PostgreSQL represents "missing text value" different than "missing integer value" or whatever? Anyway, this just helped me solve a similar problem where I had to select `NULL::boolean`

Comment: @NathanLong The issue is that the tuple type has to specify things like memory allocation.  In this case that doesn't matter but the shared infrastructure requires it.